# Oracle's cx_oracle and instantclient packages not available on anaconda/win-64

Tags: oracle, anaconda, conda, cx-oracle

I am trying to install packages **cx_Oracle** and **oracle-instantclient** via

```
conda install -c anaconda cx_oracle
conda install -c anaconda oracle-instantclient
```

The package cx_Oracle listed in https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/win-64/ and is also available under https://anaconda.org/anaconda/cx_oracle.

However, this is not the case for **oracle-instantclient**. Was the package **oracle-instantclient** removed from anaconda channel? It is not listed in https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/win-64/ and the link https://anaconda.org/anaconda/oracle-instantclient is not existent anymore.

If this is the case, where can one download this package for Windows 64 bit? And why was it removed?

Answer (score 1):

You can download Oracle Instant Client for Windows directly from OTN site:

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html

Comment: I cannot install .exe on enterprise computer, it has to be a tar.bz2 python package for installation with conda!

Comment: These downloads are .zip files (and not .exe) from which you can build your own tar.bz2 packages.